# Mapping composite primary and foreign keys with JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have two tables: A and B. Both have a composite primary key. The PK of table B is also a foreign key to the primary key of table A.

When I try to get an instance of class that maps table B I get this exception:

> org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException

The app is an Spring Boot application.
The source code is available at [Github](https://github.com/diegocairone/eiva-ejemplos)

Code source of Table B is:

```
@Entity @Table(name="usuarios")
public class UsuarioEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId @AttributeOverrides( {
        @AttributeOverride(name="perTipoUsu", column=@Column(name="per_tipo_usu", nullable=false) ), 
        @AttributeOverride(name="perCodUsu", column=@Column(name="per_cod_usu", nullable=false) ) } )
    private UsuarioPKEntity pk = null;

   @OneToOne @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
   private PersonaRelEnity personaRel = null;

   private String nombre;

   ....
}
```

Code source of Table A is:

```
@Entity @Table(name="persona_rel")
public class PersonaRelEnity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private PersonaRelPKEntity id;

    private String persona;

   ....
}
```

Both classes are at package: com.cairone.ejemplo01.entities

The complete log output is:

> 2016-09-21 12:28:24.505 ERROR 8568 --- [           main]
>   o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
>
> ```
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
>   at     org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.ja
> ```
>
> va:809) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
>         at     org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.j
>   ava:790) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
>         at     org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.
>   java:777) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
>         at     org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
>   [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
>         at     org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191
>   ) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
>         at     org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180
>   ) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
>         at com.cairone.ejemplo01.App.main(App.java:74) [classes/:na]
>       Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException:
>   org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type for
>   class com.cairone.ejemplo01.entities.PersonaRelEnity. Expected: class 
>   com.cairone.ejemplo01.entities.PersonaRelPKEntity, got class
>   com.cairone.ejemplo01.entities.UsuarioPKEntity; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type for
>   class com.cairone.ejemplo01.entities.PersonaRelEnity. Expected: class
>   com.cairone.ejemplo01.entities.PersonaRelPKEntity, got class
>   com.cairone.ejemplo01.entities.UsuarioPKEntity
>         at     org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExce
>   ptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:384) ~[spring-orm-
>   4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>         at     org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionI
>   fPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:227) ~[spring-orm-
>   4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>         at     org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExce
>   ptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:436) ~[spring-
>   orm-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>         at     org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.tran
>   slateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
>   ~    [spring-tx-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>         at     org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataA
>   ccessUtils.java:213) ~[spring-tx-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>         at     org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor
>   .invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
>   ~[spring-tx-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>         at     org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(Refle
>   ctiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-
>   4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>         at     org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProc
>   essor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetad
>   ataPostProcessor.java:131) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
>         at     org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(Refle
>   ctiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-
>   4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>         at     org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(Exp
>   oseInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-
>   4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>         at     org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(Refle
>   ctiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-
>   4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>         at     org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopP
>   roxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>         at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy69.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
>         at     com.cairone.ejemplo01.datasources.UsuarioDataSource.buscar(UsuarioDataSour
>   ce.java:15) ~[classes/:na]
>         at com.cairone.ejemplo01.App.run(App.java:33) [classes/:na]
>         at     org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.ja
>   va:806) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]     ... 6 common
>   frames omitted Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type for
>   class com.cairone.ejemplo01.entities.PersonaRelEnity. Expected: class
>   com.cairone.ejemplo01.entities.PersonaRelPKEntity, got class
>   com.cairone.ejemplo01.entities.UsuarioPKEntity    at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:455)
>   ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:67)
>   ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]  at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:323)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.4.RELEASE.jar:na]   at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:68)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.4.RELEASE.jar:na]   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_74]    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_74]    at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_74]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_74]    at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:483)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:468)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:440)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>   ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>   ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
>   ~[spring-tx-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
>   ~[spring-tx-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
>   ~[spring-tx-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>   ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
>   ~[spring-tx-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]  ... 16 common frames
>   omitted Caused by: org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of
>   the wrong type for class
>   com.cairone.ejemplo01.entities.PersonaRelEnity. Expected: class
>   com.cairone.ejemplo01.entities.PersonaRelPKEntity, got class
>   com.cairone.ejemplo01.entities.UsuarioPKEntity    at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:134)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1106)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1025)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:716)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:502)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.doInitializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:170)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:144)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:1115)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:973)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:921)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:355)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2554)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2540)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2370)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2365)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:497)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:236)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1300)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573)
>   ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:449)
>   ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]  ... 34
>   common frames omitted
>
> 2016-09-21 12:28:24.508  INFO 8568 --- [           main]
>   utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer :
>
> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration
>   report enable debug logging (start with --debug)
>
> ```
> 2016-09-21 12:28:24.509  INFO 8568 --- [           main]     s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing
> ```
>
> org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@
>   24b1d79b: startup date [Wed Sep 21 12:28:21 ART 2016]; root of context
>   hierarchy
>       2016-09-21 12:28:24.511  INFO 8568 --- [           main]     o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed
>   beans     on shutdown
>       2016-09-21 12:28:24.513  INFO 8568 --- [           main]     j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA
>   EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'

This is the relevant part:

**org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type for class com.cairone.ejemplo01.entities.PersonaRelEnity. Expected: class com.cairone.ejemplo01.entities.PersonaRelPKEntity, got class 
com.cairone.ejemplo01.entities.UsuarioPKEntity**

Comment: It would be helpful if you included the source for your `@Embeddable`s, `UsuarioPKEntity` and `PersonaRelPKEntity`.

Comment: Thanks Brian. The `@Embeddable` is an JPA annotation and th source code is available at [https://github.com/diegocairone/eiva-ejemplos]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a "derived identity", where the primary key of one entity is derived from the primary key of another, related, entity.

I have not encountered anything exactly like this relationship, but try this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="persona_rel")
public class PersonaRelEnity implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private PersonaRelPKEntity pk;

    ...
}

@Embeddable
public class PersonaRelPKEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name="per_tipo")
    private Integer perTipo;

    @Column(name="per_cod")
    private Integer perCod;

    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name="usuarios")
public class UsuarioEntity implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private UsuarioEntityPK id;

    @OneToOne
    @MapsId("personaRelPKEntity")
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="per_tipo_usu", referencedColumnName="per_tipo"),
        @JoinColumn(name="per_cod_usu", referencedColumnName="per_cod")
    })
    private PersonaRelEnity personaRelEntity = null;

    ...
}

@Embeddable
public class UsuarioEntityPK implements Serializable {

    // matches the PK type of PersonaRelEnity
    private PersonaRelPKEntity personaRelPKEntity;

    ...
}
```

Derived identities are discussed in the JPA 2.1 spec, section 2.4.1.

Side note: There is a typo in the class name `PersonaRelEnity` (i.e. `Entity` is missing its first `t`). :-)

Comment: Hi Brian. Thanks. I have implemented the changes you told me but I have a new exception: `Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.cairone.ejemplo01.entities.UsuarioEntity column: per_cod_usu (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false").`

Comment: I do not know why. The `per_tipo_usu` and `per_cod_usu` fields are marked as non-insertable and non-updateable. I've updated the code on Github: [https://github.com/diegocairone/eiva-ejemplos/tree/master/ejemplo01/src/main/java/com/cairone/ejemplo01/entities]

Comment: I do not understand your problem. Why are those columns marked non-insertable and non-updateable? Did you mark them that way?

Comment: I don't know why. Error message suggest to do that.

Comment: I uploaded a new example that it isolate the problem and a SQL script (MySQL) that recreate the database. I would appreciate if you can verify this example. It's really important to me. Thank you. [https://github.com/diegocairone/jpa-problem ]

Comment: I have updated the code in the answer to be consistent with your example classes. The only issue I see in your example is that you should remove the two `@Transient` fields in `UsuarioEntityPK` (`perTipoUsu` and `perCodUsu `). Maybe you could add the code that causes the "Provided id of wrong type..." exception.

Comment: Thanks Brian. It was very helpful. I have solved the problem with MapsId annotation